# Should I do a correction / corrigendum?

Tags: publications, errors-erratum

I published a paper two years ago, and recently I realized two sub-figures (Fig.3c and Fig.3d) in my publication are wrong. When drawing those two figures, I forgot to put one parameter in the equation so resulted in the wrong figures. Nobody has spotted this mistake yet. Now this publication has around 12 citations, but none of them really discussed anything about two wrong figures.

These two figures don't affect key conclusions at all, nor does it affect other figures at all. If I really need to publish a correction, I need to change the figure and change two sentences related to these figures. But I want to correct it anyway, for being a science guy with integrity.

So I wonder in my case, I should contact the editor and request a correction, right? I hope these mistakes wouldn't result in a retraction, and that would be really bad.

Comment: also, see [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/84980/will-i-destroy-my-career-if-i-published-a-paper-with-a-serious-mistake) and [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/110965/how-does-an-erratum-on-ones-own-paper-affect-ones-career-as-a-researcher)